# I need to be able to select a distinct dynamic xpath

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I need to select a distinct dynamic xpath in selenium between 2 pieces of xml that are identical (Dresses).  I need to create the dynamic xpath for the second value which clicks the button itself.  I have tried: `//a[@title = 'Dresses'][@class = 'sf-with-ul']` which selects both the image and the button.

Here is the code:

```
<li class="sfHoverForce" xpath="1">
    <a href="http://automationpractice.com/index.php?id_category=8&amp;controller=category" title="Dresses" class="sf-with-ul">Dresses</a>
    <ul style="display: none;">
        <li><a href="http://automationpractice.com/index.php?id_category=9&amp;controller=category" title="Casual Dresses">Casual Dresses</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://automationpractice.com/index.php?id_category=10&amp;controller=category" title="Evening Dresses">Evening Dresses</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://automationpractice.com/index.php?id_category=11&amp;controller=category" title="Summer Dresses">Summer Dresses</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li id="category-thumbnail" xpath="1">
    <div><img src="http://automationpractice.com/img/c/3-0_thumb.jpg" alt="Women" title="Women" class="imgm"></div>
    <div><img src="http://automationpractice.com/img/c/3-1_thumb.jpg" alt="Women" title="Women" class="imgm"></div>
</li>
<li class="sfHoverForce" xpath="1">
    <a href="http://automationpractice.com/index.php?id_category=8&amp;controller=category" title="Dresses" class="sf-with-ul">Dresses</a>
    <ul class="submenu-container clearfix first-in-line-xs" style="display: none;">
        <li><a href="http://automationpractice.com/index.php?id_category=9&amp;controller=category" title="Casual Dresses">Casual Dresses</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://automationpractice.com/index.php?id_category=10&amp;controller=category" title="Evening Dresses">Evening Dresses</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://automationpractice.com/index.php?id_category=11&amp;controller=category" title="Summer Dresses">Summer Dresses</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: To be more specific, the line I need to identify is the second "Dresses" .  I have tried //a[@title = 'Dresses'][@class = 'sf-with-ul'] but receive two values.

Comment: Please, can you show above of your code? maybe you need some identical parent nodes

Comment: please add the DOM/website link. Image is not the best way to display the webpage DOM.

Comment: When you post HTML and/or code please take a minute to use a beautifier like http://jsbeautifier.org/ or your IDE to properly format everything. If you need help properly formatting it on the site, see the formatting help link in the sidebar of the question editor. It makes it a LOT easier to read which makes your question more likely to get answered. Thanks!

Comment: Please post the specific URL you are on. I am looking through the site and can't find the HTML you have posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the HTML you posted, this XPath will work

```
//a[@title='Dresses'][./following-sibling::ul[contains(@class,'submenu-container')]]
^ find an A tag with a specific title
                     ^ the A tag should have a sibling UL
                                           ^ and that UL contains a specific class
```

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between the two nodes are the UL tag - class value. try this xpath to select the second node with anchor,

```
//ul[contains(@class,'submenu-container')]/preceding-sibling::a[@title='Dresses']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
//li[a[@title='Dresses']][2]/a
```

This will get the 2nd `a` element with title ‘Dresses’. If you want the first element, change the index from 2 to 1.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work either.  I toyed around with indices with no luck, either.  I feel like there might be an axes solution, but every one I tried failed.  Thank you, thought!